# Get Gradle Path while importing action sherlock project in android. Adding it as librabry

Tags: android, import, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I was just trying importing the [action sherlock library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) to my project in android studio. Once I imported the project it shows to find the gradle path:

[image]

Really can't figure out what it means? Does it want build.gradle from the action sherlock project? If so tried that too, the build.gradle does not appear in the chooser window.

[image]

But it's there when we try in the file explorer.

[image]

Do we have any way around?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to import ActionBarSherlock is to use it via a Maven coordinate-style include rather than downloading the source and trying to import it as a module. In Project settings, select your module, and from the Dependencies tab, click the + button, choose "Library dependency":

[image: Project structure dialog, showing how to add a library dependency]

. From the dialog that follows, enter the Maven coordinates `com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar`

In a more direct answer to your original question, it was asking for the path to your Gradle installation, not the build file. If you want to import modules from source, it's best to update Android Studio -- there have been fixes that went in since 0.5.2 which you're running. In the most recent versions, you can choose "Import Module" from the File menu to import modules from source.